# Generate dropdown list using session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to generate drop down list from session, I have a table and column name (state)

Delhi

Mumbai

Chennai

Goa

and I want to store those values into `session["state"]` so that I can populate these states list in drop down in other pages using `session["state"]`

I have also tried

```
DropDownList3.DataTextField = session["state"].ToString();
DropDownList3.DataSource = session["state"];
DropDownList3.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the value you have in your session.

`DropDownList3.DataSource = (DataTable)session["state"];`